# Instant trigger without a connection in custom Integromat app

Tags: make.com, integromat-apps

I am implementing an app that only contains webhooks and doesn't mention authentication in the API documentation. Is it possible to have just an instant trigger and a webhook without a connection?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question here. If it is possible, try to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). When you have a specific problem and your question formulates that specific (not broad and general) point, it is highly likely that you will get the help you are looking for; otherwise, it's hardly possible to address questions with a very generic context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A connection's main purpose is to store the credentials (sensitive data) in one place, so if the API provides no endpoints for webhook registration **or** it does, but they don't require authentication, then you can just assign the webhook to the Instant Trigger and leave the webhook's connection empty.